# Different values on writing the code in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, printf

I am solving a problem to find sum of all prime numbers till 2million, in C.
I am continuously getting wrong answer (1179908154) but when i wrote the same code in c++, it gave the correct answer (142913828922).
Please tell me why is it so, thank you.

Here is my code

```
void main()
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned long long sum;

    for(sum=2,i=3;i<=2000000;i+=2)
    {
        for(j=3;j*j<=i;j++)
            if(i%j==0)
                break;
        if(j*j>i)
            sum+=i;
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

I am on windows 7, 32 bit and using GNU GCC v4.7.1

Comment: not answering your question, but `sum=2` should not be in the loop initiailization. There's no sensible reason for that.

Comment: I wanted to start the loop from i=3 so that all even numbers could be skipped from prime test, that would exclude 2 also, that's why sum=2.

Comment: @Elazar: there is nothing wrong with the way that sum is being initialised here.

Comment: @PaulR Technically no, but the loop header is for the loop control variable. `sum` does not control the loop in any way. The OP used it to save LOC, nothing more. @sh94 The initialization itself is correct, but out of place.

Comment: @Elazar: well that's just a matter of coding style and personal preference - it's a common idiom though, and perfectly acceptable IMNVHO.

Comment: @PaulR +1 for the IMNVHO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%d` tells `printf` to expect an `int` argument. `sum` is an `unsigned long long`. This is undefined behaviour. You probably want `printf("%llu\n", sum);`.

`int` isn't a suitable type to be storing values up to `20000000`; The implementation isn't required to be able to represent values beyond `-32767` or `32767` using an `int`. You probably want `i` and `j` to be an `unsigned long` (suitable to represent positive values up to `0xFFFFFFFFUL`) or an `unsigned long long` (suitable to represent positive values up to `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL`). If you're working with values beyond that, you might want to consider using an arbitrary precision arithmetic library such as [gmplib](http://gmplib.org/).

`void main()` isn't a valid entry point in C. You probably want `int main()`.

Comment: Invalid in C++, but not technically in C. C11 allows it to be defined "in some other implementation-deﬁned manner" (§5.1.2.2.1/1), though I still wouldn't use `void main` there, either. And `int` is fine for 20 million unless your `int` is 16-bit or something, which is really not common at all anymore. The others are at least as large as you say.

Comment: Invalid in both. Valid means "there is no possibility for it to be incorrect".

Comment: @chris ... and that leads me on to respond to the edit to your comment: An assumption that an `int` can store 20000000 is invalid.

Comment: Please don't tell me you spend time making every program fully compatible with every possible configuration, obsolete or not. If your system is 16-bit, go ahead and make programs for it with that in mind. If you're doing work with other certain old machines, go ahead and confuse everyone with trigraphs to make it compatible with the keyboard. It's really not something you should need to worry about unless you're in that specific scenario.

Comment: @chris No. Effort should be made to separate standard, portable code from non-standard, non-portable code, and as much as possible of the program should be written in standard, portable code. If you write code with this in mind, then you're probably quite productive because you're significantly reducing future problems associated with code reuse in C. It's not always your choice, either. Sometimes your boss requires as much portability as possible (which includes avoiding undefined behaviour such as signed integer overflows). Ignoring your boss is a great way to get fired...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I agree, if you need to keep it in mind when writing the code, you'd better do so. I just think there's a limit to how much extra you take into account when you're almost certainly not going to run into those problems later on, which is the case for nearly everything I make, so it's mainly me talking. If I'm required to write portable code, I will do so to whatever extent is necessary. It's definitely good to at least have those considerations in mind, even if you don't need to deal with them.

Comment: @chris Fair enough. If you don't care about portability, that's your choice. Please don't attempt to brainwash others who plan on sharing their code with your pro-non-portability rants.

Comment: I have nothing against portability. I advocate it myself, such as knowing that letters don't have to be contiguous. I think it's good to know that `int` can be as little as 16 bits (which you should know if you need to write your code around that), and I definitely don't think `void main` will get you anywhere on a hosted platform. It's just that in all likelihood, `int` isn't going to *be* less than 32 bits for almost anyone now, though you could argue that against the ASCII assumption as well. Who knows, maybe I will start using `long` instead of `int` when I have 32-bit values in mind.

Comment: Isn't an integer 32-bits? If so, why is  -32767 to 32767 its range?

Answer (score 1):

Change type of `i` and `j` to `long`... and use `%ld` as format specifier. In c your value is crossing range of integer.

Comment: `sum` corresponding to `%ld` would still be undefined behaviour.

Comment: i m on 32 bit platform, and so, int is 4 bytes, doesn't exceed the range

Comment: @sh94 Choices made by your platform don't need to be adhered to by your compiler, a byte needn't necessarily be 8 bits (meaning 32 bits might not correspond to 4 bytes) and an `int` needn't occupy 4 bytes. Furthermore, there might be padding bits or trap representations that limit the range of `int`... Don't associate integer size with integer range.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that "32 bit platform" is a meaningless salesperson pitch; Even back in 1995 when the "32 bit Pentium" was released, it had 8 lots of 128 bit registers which could theoretically be used to implement `int`, and to hit the figurative nail on the head, **LP64- and LLP64- based 64-bit platforms use 32-bit `int`s**; this proves that the relationship between platform "bit size" and `int` "bit size" isn't guaranteed.